# which html helpers post back to the controller in a form?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I was kind of under the impression that any helper ending in `...For` will post back to the controller. It seems I am mistaken.  For example

```
using (Html.BeginForm(....
 @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Groups[x].Name)
```

does not post back, and I have to add a

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Groups[x].Name)
```

...to get the data.

Is there a shortcut?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `Display` templates which are used to display data on the page.

If you need to render the form you need to use `Editor` templates like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Groups[x].Name)
```

Answer (score 1):

HtmlHelpers don't postback data to the controller a such, all they do is render markup into the view, the exact markup that is rendered depends on the type being rendered.

If you want to render input controls you are better using EditorFor vs DisplayFor.

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Groups[x].Name)
```